# Historical and current size

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database which uses a Creation date field on all of the tables. How do i go about using row count and byte to get the size of tables and then get the size of the Db. Do i have to manually run a script to calculate for one table and then to the next. or can everything can be done once.

-- Any Suggestion would be appreciated

Comment: "Any Suggestion would be appreciated " first tag the correct database server MySQL isn't SQL-server.

Comment: If it's MySQL, information schema should have all the info you need.

Comment: MySql. How would i match the info from information schema to the created date in the tables

Answer (score 1):

To get the current size (approximate size from InnoDB) for the tables in your database try this

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME, DATA_LENGTH+INDEX_LENGTH size
  FROM information_schema.TABLES
 WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA=DATABASE();
```

If you want to guess the size a month ago (historical size) you can use the `TABLES.AVG_ROW_LENGTH` value, and a guesstimate of the number of rows you had back then. But that won't take index storage into account.